# What is transpiler and what is exactly work of transpiler?

Tags: javascript, transpiler

I would like to know what a transpiler is and what it actually does?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpiler

Comment: They read CoffeeScript, TypeScript, and ES2015, and spit out JavaScript guaranteed to work anywhere

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it is source-to-source compilers, are tools that read source code written in one programming language, and produce the equivalent code in another language.

Languages you write that transpile to JavaScript are often called compile-to-JS languages, and are said to target JavaScript.

> They read CoffeeScript, TypeScript, and ES2015, and spit out
>   JavaScript guaranteed to work anywhere

Try to read this [link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-transpilers-what-they-are-why-we-need-them) it is good

Comment: Languages only "target" JavaScript when they were specifically be designed to be compiled to JS.

Comment: @Bergi—better tell the people at Babel, the answer is a quote without attribution. ;-)

Comment: Please don't just quote other resources, and if you do, provide attribution. If all you have is a link, post it as a comment.

Comment: Thanks @iamsankalp89,

Answer (score 0):

Transpiler is a source to source compiler which converts code of one programming language to another programming language.Eventually we can defined the compiler which offer us target source code.
for example: if we talk about angular(specifically angular 6) which supports typescript but browser doesn't support hence transpiler comes into picture which convert typescript to javascript which can be understood by browser.